# Changing data in a text file with input from a textbox

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change the code for a listbox to use it in a textbox?

```
Private  Sub TextFile_FindReplace()

Dim y, i As Long, ii As Long

If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
y = Split(x(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex), "|")

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1
    If Me("textbox" & i + 1) <> "" Then y(i) = Me("textbox" & i + 1)
Next

x(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex) = Join(y, "|")
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\REGISTER\users.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, Join(x, vbNewLine);
Close #1
UserForm_Initialize

End sub
```

I need to use this code for a textbox as it is being used in a listbox.

I intend to use it to change data in a txt file.

For example, in the txt file I have:

> Line1 - 1|JHON|123
>   Line2 - 2|MARIE|555
>   Line3 - 3|JOSH|756

When I find number 2, I want to change the whole line by the textbox1 value.

Comment: Since a textbox is not a listbox how do you intend to use this?

Comment: I intend to use it to change data in a txt file.

for example:

 into txt file I have:
Line1 - 1|JHON|123
Line2 - 2|MARIE|555
Line3 - 3|JOSH|756

WHEN I FIND NUMBER 2, I WANT TO CHANGE THE WHOLE LINE BY THE TEXTBOX1 VALUE.

Comment: Maybe you may use .ColumnCount, . ColumnHeads, .ColumnWidths etc. of ListBox control, it allows you to show more then 1 column of your data in every row of ListBox

Comment: I want to use only textbox, not listbox.